# Set maximum image size in kb for wordpress image.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi im looking for a way to set a maximum upload size in kb for images in wordpress wp-admin/includes/image.php

This is the code i found in the image.php but i don't really understand it, any ideas on how to set a maximum value in kb or bytes

```
/**
 * Filter the image sizes automatically generated when uploading an image.
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 *
 * @param array $sizes An associative array of image sizes.
 */
$sizes = apply_filters( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', $sizes );

if ( $sizes ) {
    $editor = wp_get_image_editor( $file );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $editor ) )
        $metadata['sizes'] = $editor->multi_resize( $sizes );
} else {
    $metadata['sizes'] = array();
}
```

Here is the code that calls the image.php file maybe there is a way to add an if conditional to check the file size:

```
/**
 * Uploads file
 *
 * @access public
 * @param array $file
 * @return int
 */
public static function addFile($file, $exts=array()) {
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attachment=array(
        'ID' => 0,
    );

    $slug='file';
    if(empty($exts)) {
        $exts=array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
        $slug='image';
    }

    foreach($exts as $ext) {
        $exts[]=strtolower($ext);
        $exts[]=strtoupper($ext);
    }

    if(!empty($file['name'])) {
        $uploads=wp_upload_dir();
        $filetype=wp_check_filetype($file['name'], null);
        $filename=wp_unique_filename($uploads['path'], $slug.'-1.'.$filetype['ext']);
        $filepath=$uploads['path'].'/'.$filename;           

        //validate file
        if (!in_array($filetype['ext'], array_unique($exts))) {
            ThemexInterface::$messages[]=__('Files with this extension are not allowed', 'mercadoyorubacambio');
        } else if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $filepath)) {
```

Comment: Go to lib\external\file_uploader.php

Line 65 var $sizeLimit = 10485760;

Line 68 function __construct(array $allowedExtensions = array(), $sizeLimit = 10485760){

just change the limit. to avoid errors uses a byte converter web

Comment: Thank you i'll check on that and let you know how it works

Comment: I din't find that file but doing a search in dreamweaver i found this at wp-includes/js/pupload/handlers.min.js: `function fileUploading(a,b){var c=104857600,d=parseInt(a.settings.max_file_size,10)` I will check if changing that do the work and let you know

Comment: Nope that din't work

Answer (score 0):

I got some 'hack' for you.

All you need to do is create a php.ini file and upload it into your /wp-admin folder. Then add the following:

> memory_limit = 32M
>
> upload_max_filesize = 32M
>
> post_max_size = 32M
>
> file_uploads = On

You can set the max size by changing the '32M' to another value

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Din't work, i set it to 1M but i was able to upload a 2mb file

Answer (score 0):

```
Limit wordrpess media upload size in KB
function whero_limit_image_size($file) {

// Calculate the image size in KB
$image_size = $file['size']/1024;

// File size limit in KB
$limit = 800;

// Check if it's an image
$is_image = strpos($file['type'], 'image');

if ( ( $image_size > $limit ) && ($is_image !== false) )
        $file['error'] = 'Your picture is too large. It has to be smaller than '. $limit .'KB';

return $file;

}
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'whero_limit_image_size');
```